# VisualSVN server and disk space

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, svn, disk-space, visualsvn-server

I have an old computer which serves me as SVN server. I have also a laptop computer on which I do my work and then commit files to the server via home router.

I recently checked disk space on C: on the server computer and it was 4GB of free space. On D: however I have 16GB free space. Eventually I will run out of space on C:
I also checked some options about disk space in VisualSVN server manager but I only see options about users, groups etc...

How can I manage disk space on VisualSVN server instance or is it possible?
Or I just create new repository on D:?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to keep your data files on your "data" drive and not mix with the "system" drive. And in your case also because of a few amount of disk space available on C: disk.

To move your SVN repositories you just need to move your repositories folder to drive D: and set this new location in VisualSVN Server Manager console:

1. Open VisualSVN Server Manager,
2. Right-click on root node and select properties,
3. Change repositories location on Storage tab,
4. Click OK.

Also, don't forget to make backups of your repositories.